# Is it possible to use a variable object inside collection.find() in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, advanced-search

Context:
I am trying to code the back end of an "Advanced Search" option
It is a project I'm coding to practice JS, MongoDB(Mongoose), Next, Node, Etc.

The Schema I'm using is the following:

```
House Schema:{
 name:String,
 address:{
   street:String
   city:String,
   state:String
   },
 operations:{
   rent:Boolean, 
   shortRent:Boolean, 
   purchase:Boolean,
   agentRentPrice:Number,
   agentShortRentPrice:Number,
   agentSellingPrice:Number},
 features:{
   bathrooms:Number,
   bedrooms:Number,
   beds:Number,
   amenities:[String],
   },
}
```

Now, the FrontEnd sends the following info (in req.body):

```
query = {
  name: null,
  address: { city: null, state: null },
  operations: {
    rentAvailable: false,
    purchaseAvailable: false,
    shortRentAvailable: false,
    agentRentPriceMin: null,
    agentSellingPriceMin: null,
    agentShortRentPriceMin: null,
    agentRentPriceMax: null,
    agentSellingPriceMax: null,
    agentShortRentPriceMax: null,
  },
  features: {
    bathroomsMin: null,
    dormsMin: null,
    bedsMin: null,
    amenities: null,
  },
}
```

Of course, those "null" values will be replaced with numbers or strings with the parameters introduced by the user.

With this object, I then declare another:

```
let queryObj = {
  name: query.name,
  address: { city: query.address.city, state: query.address.state },
  operations: {
    rentAvailable: query.operations.rentAvailable,
    purchaseAvailable: query.operations.purchaseAvailable,
    shortRentAvailable: query.operations.shortRentAvailable,
    agentRentPrice: {
      $gte: query.operations.agentRentPriceMin,
      $lte: query.operations.agentRentPriceMax,
    },
    agentSellingPrice: {
      $gte: query.operations.agentSellingPriceMin,
      $lte: query.operations.agentSellingPriceMax,
    },
    agentShortRentPrice: {
      $gte: query.operations.agentShortRentPriceMin,
      $lte: query.operations.agentShortRentPriceMax,
    },
  },
  features: {
    bathrooms: { $gte: query.features.bathroomsMin },
    dorms: { $gte: query.features.dormsMin },
    beds: { $gte: query.features.bedsMin },
    amenities: { $in: query.features.amenities },
  },
}
```

Finally I reduce this object, removing any "null", "false", "" and "{}" values.

For example, the user searches for: house available for renting, in New York, with 2 bedrooms, with a pool, and max Rent price of $10.000

So, req.body.query will be

```
{
  name: null,
  address: { city: "New York", state: null },
  operations: {
    rentAvailable: true,
    purchaseAvailable: false,
    shortRentAvailable: false,
    agentRentPriceMin: null,
    agentSellingPriceMin: null,
    agentShortRentPriceMin: null,
    agentRentPriceMax: 10000,
    agentSellingPriceMax: null,
    agentShortRentPriceMax: null,
  },
  features: {
    bathroomsMin: null,
    dormsMin: 2,
    bedsMin: null,
    amenities: ["pool"],
  },
}
```

Next, I declare

```
let queryObj = {
  name: null,
  address: { city: "New York", state: null },
  operations: {
    rentAvailable: true,
    purchaseAvailable: false,
    shortRentAvailable: false,
    agentRentPrice: {
      $gte: null,
      $lte: 10000,
    },
    agentSellingPrice: {
      $gte: null,
      $lte: null,
    },
    agentShortRentPrice: {
      $gte: null,
      $lte: null,
    },
  },
  features: {
    bathrooms: { $gte: null },
    dorms: { $gte: 2 },
    beds: { $gte: null },
    amenities: { $in: ["pool"] },
  },
};
```

I have a function here that reduces this object (removing "false" "null" "" and "{}" values):

```
queryObj = {
  address: { city: "New York" },
  operations: {
    rentAvailable: true,
    agentRentPrice: {
      $lte: 10000,
    },
  },
  features: {
    dorms: { $gte: 2 },
    amenities: { $in: ["pool"] },
  },
};
```

As you can see, "query" (and therefore "queryObj") will vary a lot; the user may or may not use any of the available search parameters, so (as i see it) it is not possible to "hard-code" the queryObj structure

I've tried using

```
Home.aggregate([{$match:queryObj}])
```

without success (returns no results).

Is it possible what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I think what you need is one more step - convert your query object (`queryObj`) to _dot notation_.  I.e., `address: { city: "New York" }` needs to become `"address.city": "New York"`.  Currently, I think what `address: { city: "New York" }` means to the MongoDB server is that `address` is exactly equal to `{ city: "New York" }`, so if `address` in the collection was `{ city: "New York", state: "NY" }`, there would be no match.  I'm pretty sure there are npm packages that will do the _dot conversion_.

Comment: From what i understand, this is exactly what is happening; and my problem is that final step. Having said that, I never thought of searching for a npm package... thanks

Comment: There are several packages that may be useful.  For example, `var mongoDotNotationTool = require("mongo-dot-notation-tool"); const queryObjFlat = mongoDotNotationTool.encode(queryObj);`.  I haven't used any of the packages, so you should test thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a function to build the filter:

```js
const body = {
  name: null,
  address: { city: 'New York', state: null },
  operations: {
    rentAvailable: true,
    purchaseAvailable: false,
    shortRentAvailable: false,
    agentRentPriceMin: null,
    agentSellingPriceMin: null,
    agentShortRentPriceMin: null,
    agentRentPriceMax: 10000,
    agentSellingPriceMax: null,
    agentShortRentPriceMax: null,
  },
  features: {
    bathroomsMin: null,
    dormsMin: 2,
    bedsMin: null,
    amenities: ['pool'],
  },
};

const buildFilter = (body) => {
  const filter = {};
  if (body.name != null) {
    filter['name'] = body.name;
  }
  if (body.address.city != null) {
    filter['address.city'] = body.address.city;
  }
  if (body.address.state != null) {
    filter['address.state'] = body.address.state;
  }
  if (body.operations.rentAvailable != null) {
    filter['operations.rentAvailable'] = body.operations.rentAvailable;
  }
  if (body.operations.purchaseAvailable != null) {
    filter['operations.purchaseAvailable'] = body.operations.purchaseAvailable;
  }
  if (body.operations.shortRentAvailable != null) {
    filter['operations.shortRentAvailable'] =
      body.operations.shortRentAvailable;
  }
  let agentRentPrice = {};
  if (body.operations.agentRentPriceMin != null) {
    agentRentPrice = { $gte: body.operations.agentRentPriceMin };
  }
  if (body.operations.agentRentPriceMax != null) {
    agentRentPrice = {
      ...agentRentPrice,
      $lte: body.operations.agentRentPriceMax,
    };
  }
  if (Object.keys(agentRentPrice).length > 0) {
    filter['operations.agentRentPrice'] = agentRentPrice;
  }
  let agentSellingPrice = {};
  if (body.operations.agentSellingPriceMin != null) {
    agentSellingPrice = { $gte: body.operations.agentSellingPriceMin };
  }
  if (body.operations.agentSellingPriceMax != null) {
    agentSellingPrice = {
      ...agentSellingPrice,
      $lte: body.operations.agentSellingPriceMax,
    };
  }
  if (Object.keys(agentSellingPrice).length > 0) {
    filter['operations.agentSellingPrice'] = agentSellingPrice;
  }
  let agentShortRentPrice = {};
  if (body.operations.agentShortRentPriceMin != null) {
    agentShortRentPrice = { $gte: body.operations.agentShortRentPriceMin };
  }
  if (body.operations.agentShortRentPriceMax != null) {
    agentShortRentPrice = {
      ...agentShortRentPrice,
      $lte: body.operations.agentShortRentPriceMax,
    };
  }
  if (Object.keys(agentShortRentPrice).length > 0) {
    filter['operations.agentShortRentPrice'] = agentShortRentPrice;
  }
  if (body.features.bathrooms != null) {
    filter['features.bathrooms'] = { $gte: body.features.bathrooms };
  }
  if (body.features.dorms != null) {
    filter['features.dorms'] = { $gte: body.features.dorms };
  }
  if (body.features.beds != null) {
    filter['features.beds'] = { $gte: body.features.beds };
  }
  if (body.features.amenities != null) {
    filter['features.amenities'] = { $in: body.features.amenities };
  }
  return filter;
};

console.log(buildFilter(body));
```

A little verbose, but it is due to the fact that you don't have a 1-on-1 correspondence between the attributes of the body and your filter's properties.

Comment: I had to tweak it a little; there were cases where it returned embeded empty objects (i.e: if the query had agentRentPriceMax and agentRentPriceMin in null; the function assigned operations.agentRentPrice:{}; and this returned a CastError Error.)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating the filter dynamically on the backend. Basically, you will start with an empty filter, and then you will check each user input, and add it to the filter if exists. That way, you don't have to worry if the user will send multiple filters, or if it will not send filters at all. Everything will be added dynamically.

```js
const queryObj = {
  address: { city: "New York" },
  operations: {
    rentAvailable: true,
    agentRentPrice: {
      $lte: 10000,
    },
  },
  features: {
    dorms: { $gte: 2 },
    amenities: { $in: ["pool"] },
  },
};

// Initialize empty filter.
const filter = {};

if (queryObj?.address?.city) filter['address.city'] = queryObj.address.city;

if (typeof queryObj?.operations?.rentAvailable === boolean) filter['operations.rentAvailable'] = queryObj.operations.rentAvailable;

if (queryObj?.operations?.agentRentPrice?.$lte) filter['operations.agentRentPrice'] = { $lte: queryObj.operations.agentRentPrice.$lte };
```